# Create a hyperlink using text from input

Tags: html, hyperlink

so I basically want to utilize Whatsapp Web ability message people who are not in my contact. I whatsapp a lot of people and It's just not practical to save each and everyone of them to my contact list.

To do that, I simply need to insert this url into my browser:

https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=

and insert the number after the equal mark.

I made a simple input tag, but I don't know how to make my submit button open the Whatsapp's api link and also add the number I put in the input box.

Thanks

Comment: You might be looking for the `action=""` attribute on the `<form>` tag.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to spam. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MathieuK.no, I'm in charge for contacting training firm with real credibilities. I have to contact a lot of them just to find the ones with official certification.

Comment: @Evert yes, I understand that, what I have no idea is what to put inside the action tag

Comment: You put the url.